# Grant access to save queries in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to grant users a permission to save their own queries.

Granted "All" to [Discover and Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Ke6.png).

For now users see "save query" as "read-only". I've tried and turning on/off "Advanced Settings", "Saved Objects Management" - nothing works. Is there a way to turn this feature on easily without installing OSQuery ? (installed on another cluster, setting it to "All" did a thing)

For now Management in user settings looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhkhy.png). Should I change to "All" some of those?

Using ElasticSearch 7.13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the users were in the wrong group.

Should've been closed this question about a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow users to save their own queries in Elasticsearch, you will need to grant them the "save" and "save_object" cluster privileges. You can do this by navigating to the "Cluster Privileges" section in the Elasticsearch Management interface, and editing the relevant user or role to include those privileges.

You may need to set the "All" permissions in the Discover and Dashboard, and also check if the user has the save and save_object index privilege on the index they are trying to save queries on.

Additionally, you should check if the user has the manage_saved_objects role. If the user does not have this role, you can assign it to them in the "Roles" section of the Elasticsearch Management interface.

Also, you can check the index-level permissions in index management, if the user has the necessary permissions to create, update and delete saved objects in the index.

Comment: Unfortunately there no "save" and "save_object" privileges in "Cluster Privileges". "All" is set up in "Discover" and "Dashboard" but it doesn't help. And there are no "manage_saved_objects" role for me. About index-level permissions: there are "write" permission but this is such a big privilege to user to work with